# Partially print char buffer

Tags: c, buffer, partial, fwrite, cat

I want to implement a `cat` or `more` style command for a user defined shell I'm building.

The twist I want to add is to allow the user to press the spacebar to print the next x-lines.

So I have the following code which prints out the entire char buffer...

```
int user_more(char argc, char *argv){
  char buf[64];
  FILE *file;
  size_t nread;

  file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  if (file) {
      while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file)) > 0)
          fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
      if (ferror(file)) {
          /* deal with error */
          printf("There was an error opening your file. Please check the name and try again.\n");
      }
      fclose(file);
  }
}
```

So to clarify, I want to first print out the first x-lines then after the user presses the space bar, I want to print out the next x-lines.

**

### SOLUTION

**

this implementatio requires the user to input n because I can't utilize the conio.h library (to user arrow keys)

```
while (1){
        //print out first four lines
        if (j == 1){
          for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
            printf("%s", buf);
          }
          j++;
        }
        scanf(" %c", &next);
        if (next == 'n'){
          //spacebear has been pressed
          //loop +4 times and only print the last 4 lines
          for (i = 0; i < k; i++){
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
            if (i == k-4 || i == k-3 || i == k-2 || i == k-1){
              printf("%s", buf);
            }
          }
          k += 4;
        }

      }
```

Comment: If you want to print lines, the easiest solution is to use [a function which reads lines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).